# Как переместить фокус на предыдущее поле ввода при нажатии BackSpace на пустом поле?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Дано: NativeScript-core форма с однородными полями типа:

```xml
<TextField text="{{ number }}" hint="" maxLength="1" keyboardType="number"/>
```

Если фокус находиться на пустом поле, и пользователь нажимает BackSpace, можно ли переместить фокус на предыдущее поле ввода? Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: js event onkeyup => if keyCode == 8 (8 - backspace/пробел) mаke next field focus. Хотите больше - дайте воспроизводимый пример и кто-то поможет

Comment: Похоже, в NativeScript-core нет «нативной» поддержки события onKeyUp для полей TextField.

Comment: Года пол назад нужно было мне enter чекать - я не нашел как это сделать средствами ns, доделывал на js